# Experimental comparison and variants

Tags: r

Could anybody explain this code from Luis Torgo (the [DMwR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DMwR/)):

```
cv.rpart <- function(form, train, test, ...) {
  m   <- rpartXse(form, train, ...)
  p   <- predict(m, test)
  mse <- mean( (p-resp(form,test))^2 )
  c(  nmse=mse/mean( (mean(resp(form,train))-resp(form,test))^2 )  )
}
cv.lm <- function(form, train, test, ...) {
  m   <- lm(form, train,...)
  p   <- predict(m, test)
  p   <- ifelse(p<0, 0, p)
  mse <- mean( (p-resp(form,test))^2 )
  c(  nmse=mse/mean( (mean(resp(form,train))-resp(form,test))^2 )  )
}

res <- experimentalComparison(c(dataset(a1 ~ .,clean.algae[,1:12],'a1')),
                              c(variants('cv.lm'), variants('cv.rpart',se=c(0,0.5,1))),
                              cvSettings(3,10,1234)
                              )
```

How will `experimentalComparison` use `cv.rpart` and `cv.lm`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for here? Do you want to understand how the code implements the ideas / what the code says / how the code works, OR are you asking what the underlying ideas are / how the ideas are related to the task of comparing models?

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply but i want to know what the code says in experimental comparison esp with variants(cv.lm) and cv,rpart

Answer (score 1):

`cv.lm` and `cv.rpart` perform cross-validation on the linear model and the decision trees models, respectively.  For the decision trees, in `experimentalComparison`, we also specify different complexity parameters.

If you run `plot(res)` at the end, as Torgo has it in his code, you can see the boxplots of the errors for the 4 models (1 lm + 3 rpart).

I've commented the lines below.

```
# this function combines training, cross-validation, pruning, prediction,
# and metric calculation
cv.rpart <- function(form, train, test, ...) {
  # rpartXse grows a tree and calculates the cross-validation error
  # at each node.  It then determines the best tree based on the 
  # the results of this cross-validation.
  # Torgo details how the optimal tree based on 
  # cross-validation results is chosen
  # earlier in his code
  m   <- rpartXse(form, train, ...)   
  # use m to predict on test set
  p   <- predict(m, test)
  # calculates normalized mean square error
  # Refer https://rem.jrc.ec.europa.eu/RemWeb/atmes2/20b.htm
  # for details on NMSE
  mse <- mean( (p-resp(form,test))^2 )
  c(  nmse=mse/mean( (mean(resp(form,train))-resp(form,test))^2 )  )
}


cv.lm <- function(form, train, test, ...) {
  m   <- lm(form, train,...)
  p   <- predict(m, test)
  p   <- ifelse(p<0, 0, p)
  mse <- mean( (p-resp(form,test))^2 )
  c(  nmse=mse/mean( (mean(resp(form,train))-resp(form,test))^2 )  )
}

# experimental comparison is designed to create numerous models 
# based on parameters you provide it

# Arguments of experimentalComparison function are
# Dataset class object
# learner class object (contains the learning systems that will be used)
# settings class object
# These datatypes are unique to the DMwR package
# dataset is a function that creates a dataset object (a list)
# each element of the list contains the response variable
# and the actual data
res <- experimentalComparison(
             c(dataset(a1 ~ .,clean.algae[,1:12],'a1')),
             c(variants('cv.lm'), 
              # se specifies the number of standard errors to
              # use in the post-pruning of the tree
              variants('cv.rpart',se=c(0,0.5,1))),
             # cvSettings specifies 3 repetitions of 10-fold
             # cross-validation
             # with a seed of 1234
             cvSettings(3,10,1234)
                              )
```

`summary(res)` gives you basic statistics for the cross-validation results of each model.